# Mount disk fails via Flask rest api but works when run directly on command line or shell script

Tags: python, shell, flask, mount, flask-restful

I am trying to run a mount command using Flask rest api.
I have tried multiple ways, but none of them works. 
However when I directly execute the command on the VM it runs fine. I checked that user running in rest has privileges.

1) `os.system('sudo mount -a')`

2) using subprocess to call a shell script

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

I see this error when executing from rest api. However no issues when executing directly.

mount: /dev/sdc1 is already mounted or /u01/data busy
       /dev/sdc1 is already mounted on /u01/data

Comment: Does "sudo mount -a" ask for a password when you run it from a terminal and logged in as the user that owns the Flask worker ?

Comment: no it doesn't ask when i run directly terminal or via the shell script

Comment: Write the `sudo` command in a shell script  and call that via flask and then via shell. Record the return value ($?) and redirect stdout and stderr to a file to inspect. Maybe even diff env variables (`env > env.vars`).

Comment: i see that root user runs with this context in flask **context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0**, is this causing the issue?

Comment: Though I could not figure out whats the cause, I got around the issue by using command to start the mount service created by fstab generator `sudo systemctl start u01-data.mount`  `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` , this gets executed fine when called via flask via shell script